# How to drop duplicates while keeping records based on time difference condition?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following pandas data frame `df`:

```
Datetime              NewDatetime            Value
2020-03-24 09:00      2020-03-24 12:00       10 
2020-03-24 09:00      2020-03-24 13:00       11
2020-03-24 09:00      2020-03-24 14:00       10
2020-03-24 09:00      2020-03-24 15:00       12
2020-03-24 10:00      2020-03-24 12:00       10 
2020-03-24 10:00      2020-03-24 13:00       11
2020-03-24 10:00      2020-03-24 14:00       11
2020-03-24 10:00      2020-03-24 15:00       12
2020-03-24 11:00      2020-03-24 12:00       10 
2020-03-24 11:00      2020-03-24 13:00       16
2020-03-24 11:00      2020-03-24 14:00       11
2020-03-24 11:00      2020-03-24 15:00       12
2020-03-24 12:00      2020-03-24 12:00       12 
2020-03-24 12:00      2020-03-24 13:00       13
2020-03-24 12:00      2020-03-24 14:00       11
2020-03-24 12:00      2020-03-24 15:00       15
```

I need to drop duplicates by `NewDatetime` and keep such records that have the difference between `NewDatetime` and `Datetime` equal to 3 hours.

This is the expected result:

```
Datetime              NewDatetime            Value
2020-03-24 09:00      2020-03-24 12:00       10  
2020-03-24 10:00      2020-03-24 13:00       11
2020-03-24 11:00      2020-03-24 14:00       11
2020-03-24 12:00      2020-03-24 15:00       15
```

How can I do it?

I know how to drop duplicates and keep the last records, but not sure how to add the condition of time difference:

```
df.drop_duplicates(["NewDatetime"], keep='last')
```

Comment: Where are you stuck?  You give a well-defined pair of operations.  Apply them in sequence: remove the ones with less than three hours' difference, and then drop_duplicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
df['Datetime']=pd.to_datetime(df['Datetime'])
df['NewDatetime']=pd.to_datetime(df['NewDatetime'])
#ensure that both columns are of datetime dtype
```

Then:

```
m=((df['NewDatetime']-df['Datetime']).dt.total_seconds()/3600).eq(3)
#check your condition If the difference between these 2 is equal to 3 hrs or not
```

Finally:

```
df[m]
#OR
df.loc[m]
#passed the condition
```

Comment: Why not just `seconds` instead of `total_seconds()`?

Comment: @not_speshal if you got time delta in `+1 days 03:00:00` then it means 27 hrs but when you use `.dt.seconds` it gives you `10800` seconds but if you use `.dt.total_seconds()` it will gives you `97200.0` seconds

Answer (score 1):

you can use the TimeDelta object to compare i think.

```py
In [32]: (pd.to_datetime('2020-03-24 12:00') - pd.to_datetime('2020-03-24 09:00')) == pd.Timedelta('3 hours')
Out[32]: True

In [33]: (pd.to_datetime('2020-03-24 12:00') - pd.to_datetime('2020-03-24 09:12')) == pd.Timedelta('3 hours')
Out[33]: False
```